# UIStoryboards, UITableViewControllers, and UIToolbars: Can't Place The Toolbar Where I Want

Tags: uitableview, uitoolbar, uistoryboard, ios5

This breaking my head because I can't seem to find a way to do it. I want to put a UIToolbar directly on top of a UITabBar, but whenever I drag the component, it goes and gets added below a UITableViewCell.

This is what happens:

[image]

The toolbar should be below, on top of the tab bar, not below the UITableViewCell. These cells are dynamic, not static (if it matters).

Any help will be really appreciated!

EDIT: I just figured it's adding the toolbar as a cell rather than as another component. I can't seem to add the toolbar outside the table though. Uuuhhgh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a ViewController, not a TableViewController.

Drag out the TableView into the ViewController and resize it accordingly, then add the UIToolBar below it.

Hope it works.

Comment: This is far from ideal, but since it's the only thing that made it work, I will do this for now. Regardless, I'm not marking your question as accepted yet just in case someone finds a better solution. But thanks a lot for the workaround for now!

Comment: Happy to get you going first. :)

Comment: After doing research for a couple of days turn's out there's no sane way to do this. Regardless, I changed my design because it looked ugly anyway. Still, I thank you a lot for your answer.